# $.getJSON request is behaving in a way I am unclear about. Not sure how to format the request with callback=?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Of three jquery json requests, one of them is giving cross-domain errors because I don't know how to include the callback=? (or really why that denotes json vs jsonp).

Two requests to the same api, just one uses parameters and it's new to me on why it's not working (i've tried adding the &callback=? and other such solutions.)

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/hCWwT/10/

```
var names = ["athenelive", "riotgames", "aphromoo"];

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name": {"life": "{life}","logo": "{logo}","status": "{status}","preview": "{preview}","url": "{url}"}}');

wtfJSON();

function wtfJSON() {

for (index = 0; index < names.length; ++index) {

    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + names[index] + "/?callback=?", function (json) {

        $('body').append("Stufffff: " + obj.name.logo + "<br>");

        $('body').append("Name: " + json.name + "<br>");
        $('body').append("Logo: " + json.logo + "<br>");
        $('body').append("Status(title): " + json.status + "<br>");
        $('body').append("URL: " + json.url + "<br>");

    });

    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + names[index] + "/?callback=?", function (json) {
        if (json.stream !== null) {

            $('body').append("Preview: " + json.stream.preview.medium + "<br>");

        }
    });

    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + names[index] + "/videos?limit=3&broadcasts=true$callback=?", function (json) {

        $('body').append("Video Name: " + json + "<br>");

    });
}
}
```

Comment: You have `$callback` instead of `&callback` in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/athenelive/videos?limit=3&broadcasts=true. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Using `$.getJSON` with a `callback` argument actually sends a JSONP request, which jQuery implements by just creating a `<script>` tag and using a unique global callback. Without it, you attempt to send a regular AJAX request to that other website, which isn't allowed by your browser.

Add a `callback` parameter and it'll work:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + names[index] + "/videos?limit=3&broadcasts=true&callback=?", function (json) {
```

Comment: I've done that and it is still behaving in a weird way. That was what prompted the question.

I've updated the fiddle to show

Comment: @Qwiso: You put a dollar sign instead of an ampersand in the URL.

Comment: @Blender well i did say this was a simple problem. thanks everyone! :D