# How to use JQuery to Access Twitch streams

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so I want to access each twitch stream name in an array, then push to an html div a link to each online stream and its logo.  The problem is that I just don't know how to do this, or where to begin really.  I've read the documentation about twitch api calls, but either I'mvbeing thick or I'm missing something else.

This is my javascript:

```
var possibleChannels= ["storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx","RobotCaleb","comster404","brunofin","thomasballinger","noobs2ninjas","beohoff"];

possibleChannels.forEach(function(element){
$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + element, 
function(channel){
if (channel["stream"] == null) { 
   ($"All").append("<p>Paragraph</p>");
} 
else {
   ($"All").append("<p>Paragraph</p>");   
}
});
}
```

The "paragraph" text is just to see if I can actually write text to the html document, and "All" is a div element I have set up.
Am I accessing the twitch stream correctly?
Any help is appreciated, even if it is the "go to google and type this in" kind of help.

Comment: I don't know diddly about Twitch's api but you've got a syntax error. `($"All")` isn't right. Something like `$('.all')` would work, depending on your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example but was not able to get it to work correctly until I put a '?callback=?' [as suggested in another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645614/getjson-request-is-behaving-in-a-way-i-am-unclear-about-not-sure-how-to-forma). Here is a working example:

```
var possibleChannels= ["storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx","RobotCaleb","comster404","brunofin","thomasballinger","noobs2ninjas","beohoff"];

possibleChannels.forEach(function(name){
$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + name + '?callback=?', 
    function(channel){
        if (channel["stream"] == null) {
            $("#all").append("<p>" + channel._links.self + "</p>");
        } 
        else {
           $("#all").append("<p>Fail</p>");   
        }
    });
});
```

You also have the issue with `($"All)` as pointed out by Scheda. I used an id tag in the JSFiddle example.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rnhm3xfL/